# In a single MySQL query lookup one column's value in another table

Tags: php, mysql

In table `f_stock` I have a list of all items in an inventory. The integer in the `type` column refers to the `id` in table `f_type`.

I want to output the contents of table `f_stock` with `f_type.id` in place of `f_stock.type`. How is this done?

In the past I have done something along these lines:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `f_stock`";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error ());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
print_r ($data);
```

To lookup the integer `f_stock.type` in the `f_type.id` column I have created a secondary $query/$result inside the *while* loop.

Table `f_stock`:

```
`type` | `size` | `length`
-------|--------|---------
   1   |   3    |    12
   1   |   3    |    16   
   2   |   3    |    20   
   2   |   3    |    25   
   1   |   4    |    12   
   1   |   4    |    16   
   3   |   4    |    20
```

Table `f_type`:

```
 `id` |  `type` 
------|---------
   1  | 'Type 1'
   2  | 'Type 2'
   3  | 'Type 3'
   4  | 'Type 4'
   5  | 'Type 5'
   6  | 'Type 6'
   7  | 'Type 7'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [JOIN](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sql%20join).

```
SELECT `f_stock`.`size`, `f_stock`.`length`, `f_type`.`type`
FROM `f_stock`
LEFT JOIN `f_type` ON `f_type`.`id` = `f_stock`.`type`
```

-edit-
@Bruno Vieira's is actually better, you should use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. The reason being that an `INNER JOIN` only returns the `f_stock` rows with a matching `f_type` row. If `f_stock.type` is NULL, or if no `f_type` with the given `id` exists, the `f_stock` row will not be returned. `LEFT JOIN` returns all `f_stock` rows, and then tries to match them with an `f_type` row if possible.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should avoid using the `mysql` php functions. Use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

You can solve your problem by simply using a `LEFT JOIN` statement like the following

```
SELECT `f_stock`.`size`, `f_stock`.`length`, `f_type`.`type`
FROM `f_stock` 
LEFT JOIN `f_type` on `f_type`.`id`=`f_stock`.`type`;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this query outputs an id and the corresponding type string for every item in the stock table. It doesn't output the size and length like the other two answers do. Thanks for the PDO and MySQLi links.

Comment: Ok, it was meant to be an example of using LEFT JOIN. I'll edit the answer by the way

Comment: Now it'll outputs the way you want. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

#### You can use MySQL Joins

Use this query in your DB.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `f_stock`, `f_type` WHERE `f_stock`.`type` = `f_type`.`id`";
```

#### MySQL Code:

```
SELECT `f_stock`.`type` as `type`, `size`, `length` FROM `f_stock`, `f_type`
  WHERE `f_stock`.`type` = `f_type`.`id`
```

#### Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58892/2

#### Output:

```
+------+------+--------+
| TYPE | SIZE | LENGTH |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    3 |     12 |
|    1 |    3 |     16 |
|    1 |    4 |     12 |
|    1 |    4 |     16 |
|    2 |    3 |     20 |
|    2 |    3 |     25 |
|    3 |    4 |     20 |
+------+------+--------+
```

Comment: You hero, that works perfectly - thank you. I was having trouble finding examples because I couldn't express what I wanted concisely enough.